# Как десериализовать объект который содержит другой объект?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот класс который я хочу десеализировать

```
[Serializable]
public class Responce
{
    public Exeption Exeption;
    public object resultObj;
    public string Id;
}
```

Вот сам json

```
{"Exeption":null,"Id":"f929acbf-7e2a-4482-8049-1b75a2abe40d","resultObj":"904c7b42f5c42a081111129b8efd0133"}
```

Я хочу чтоб object мог быть любым классом при десеализации
Использую JsonUtility из UnityEngine

Comment: `resultObj` это `string` а не `object`

Comment: я иммею в ввиду то что вместо этого string может быть любой другой класс

Comment: Ну присваивайте любой другой класс туда, не вижу проблемы.

Comment: Проблема в том то что я хочу использовать иммено тип object но при его использовании выдаёт null

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Покажите модель, покажите код сериализации, покажите JSON который получается после сериализации, потом покажите как вы его десереализуете, и объясните, на каком из этих этапов у вас null.

Comment: Я беру json с tcp сервера который написан на js. Вот пример модели игрока `[Serializable]
 public class PlayerJson
 {
  public string PlayerUid;

  public string Name;

  public int TimeInGame;

  public long RegistrationDate;

  public string AvatarId;

  public string Id;
 }`. `{"Exeption":null,"Id":"3e5e8221-32aa-45b6-a7f2-a45535a66667","resultObj":{"AvatarId":"","PlayerUid":"786","Id":"7475769d0a2c7bb5ef7a1ef766cd049c","Name":"TK_6546","RegistrationDate":1666291617475,"TimeInGame":0}}`вот json который выдаётся после запроса на сервер.

Comment: дополнение*
null при ретурне jsonObj десеарилизация происходит при получении ответа от сервера и добавление в список Responce потом его достаю благодаря уникальному guid после получения его, ретурнаю resultObj который почему-то равен null

Comment: Пожалуйта не вставляйте большие куски кода в комменты, отредактируйте сам вопрос.

Comment: Сериализатор не будет десирилизовать то, не знамо что, ему нужен конкретный тип. И даже не наследник некого декларируемого типа, а именно тот который указан! И этот тип тоже должен быть `[Serializable]`.